# Could I just always flush a write ahead log instead of implementing a Two-Phase Commit protocol?

Tags: database, transactions, commit, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

I have trouble understanding parts of the [two-phase commit protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol). I don't understand how the second phase helps at all.

As far as I understand, the second (completion) phase can fail just as if we had only one phase. Do we need the second phase to ensure that disk failures are caught when flushing a write-ahead log? If so, wouldn't it make sense to constantly flush the write-ahead log instead and avoid slow network communication and latency?

Answer (score 0):

Two phase commit protocol is to have transaction across multiple different entities.

Consider an example 
Name: User1, Balance: $100
Name: User2, Balance: $200

Now lets say in a transaction you transferred $50 from User1 to User2. Now after transaction balance should become

Name: User1, Balance: $50

Name: User2, Balance: $250

---

hence there are 2 steps

```
void Transaction(int amount)
{
  User2.Add(amount);
  User1.Subtract(amount);
}
```

Now what if amount is $150 in that case User1.Subtract(amount) will fail(as balance cannot be negative), while User2.Add(amount) would have succeeded.

To perform various validations "Voting" phase is required. "Commit" phase exist to atomically say yes/no to complete transaction. Very simple pseudo-code for 2-phase is:

```
bool Perform_Two_Phase_Transaction(int amount)
{
  var addVote = User2.VoteFor_Add(amount);
  var subtractVote = User1.VoteFor_Subtract(amount);
  if(addVote && subtractVote)
  {
    var addCommit = User2.Commit();
    var subtractCommit = User1.Commit();
    if(addCommit && subtractCommit)
    {
      return true;
    }
    if(addCommit)
    {
      User2.Rollback();
      return false;
    }
    if(subtractCommit)
    {
      User1.Rollback();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```